# The Kindle app on my iPhone 4s isn't downloading books

Tags: iphone, kindle

I've been using the Kindle reader app on my iPhone and it was working as advertised for a while. However, yesterday for no apparent reason it has stopped being able to download books. I bought a book, went to my list of books in the Kindle app, and tapped the "download" control. The message reads "Downloading 0.0%" and just stays there. I tried downloading another recent purchase. Same deal. I tried restarting the Kindle app, and then the iPhone, but that didn't help. I tried going onto the Amazon and "sending" the books to my iPhone with no result. I made sure the iPhone is connected to my home wi-fi network.

Has anyone else seen this problem? Know of a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You say it suddenly started working again?

My best guess is that it was caused by [GoDaddy's DNS servers going down.](http://mashable.com/2012/09/10/godaddy-down/)  This has caused generally odd behavior across the internet as many sites and URLs were 'forgotten' temporarily.  Many sites became unreachable.

There's a chance the Kindle downloading mechanism relied on an address that was affected.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted the iPhone again and now it's working.

No idea why it wasn't working before.